# Redux state is being changed but props are undefined when using mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I am using React-redux in my app and I have encountered this problem where I am using `connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Component)` and am able to successfuly manipulate the redux state with the mapped dispatch. Using the dev tools I see that the state has changed successfully, but the mapped props are always undefined in any component.

Example component where I am trying it:

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.idToken);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="dashboard-container">
                <p>{this.props.idToken}</p>

                <button onClick={() =>  {this.props.logout()}}>
                    LOGOUT
                </button>
            <button onClick={() =>  {browserHistory.push('/app/play')}}>
                    PLAY
                </button>
            <button onClick={() =>  {this.props.setIsLoading(true)}}>
                    TEST
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    idToken: state.idToken,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout, setIsLoading })(DashboardPage);
```

However, this has been working before. I took a break from the code for a while so I don't exactly remember what I have changed to break this, but I am quite sure it has something to do with React router so here's my routes:

```
export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="app" component={Authorized}>
            <IndexRedirect to="/app/dashboard"/>
            <Route path="dashboard" component={DashboardPage} />
            <Route path="play" component={PlayPage}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
);
```

I am basically using `App` as the main container, where I call a thunk action that checks whether there's a token in localStorage and then if yes, calls and action that reapplies the token state (the same action called on successfull login). This action, before reapplying the state, redirects the user to `/app/dashboard` , if there are no credentials saved in localStorage, the app redirects to  `/login` automatically.

my `index.js`:

```
const appRoot = document.getElementById('app-root');

const store = createStore(reducers, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , appRoot);
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong about the routing, that makes `mapStateToProps` not return the props correctly ?

Thanks in advance for help.

EDIT: I just edited my `mapStateToProps` to this, in order to see whether the state gets passed:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    idToken: state.idToken,
  };
};
```

and the log output is `undefined`

Comment: Where's your [`<Provider />`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it and added a snippet with it now, though I am pretty sure that should be correct as I haven't changed anything there since it was working

Comment: How do you keep in sync your router and your redux store ? What is `browserHistory` ? I am not sure it will solves the problem, if that can help I use `react-router-redux` binding with this config https://gist.github.com/vnctaing/9359f0224b7c004ced6396b8a1b022dd

Comment: `browserHistory` is just the browser history imported from react-router. I am sure `react-roiter-redux` is not going to help me. The router and redux should work together without any bindings

Comment: if mapped props are undefined, can you share your reducer code? What makes you think that your router is causing the issue?

Comment: @AnthonyChung nothing in particular, its a long shot but I think I have changed something with the routes and the props have been undefined since. I am on my phone right now so I can share the reducers code but that shouldn't be a problem if I can see the state changing in Redux Dev Tools, right ?

Comment: @valorl Please share your reducer code and your complete index.js file. I can't see any reason why react-router should mess up with your state.

Comment: Agreed, this is most likely a reducer problem

Comment: Yeah. Edit and put your reducers for us to see what is happening.

Comment: Another possibility is an [update block](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md) problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you did not add your previous state in reducer when you updated your state. For example if your new state is return {action.something}, then it might be {...state , action.something}. i had such problem. i am not expert, still working and learning.